# Using custom form in Outlook when creating a new mail message

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-form

I want to create a custom form in Outlook 2007 and then have that form be the form that comes up when the user clicks New / Mail Message in the toolbar.  Is there a way to do that?  I know how to create the custom form, but I don't know how to change what the menu item does.

Jon

Comment: Not sure this is programming related -- ServerFault may be a better place for it...

Comment: Yes, it is programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an outlook form you can publish it to the Organizational Forms Library and the get you clients to use that new custom form instead of the default out the box form. It a registry change that points it to a new form. There are tools to do this change for you.

A good example http://www.petri.co.il/customizing_new_meeting_request_outlook_form.htm

76mel

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial by Ty Anderson on that located at [devx](http://www.devx.com/MicrosoftISV/Article/29261/2213) on replacing the standard AppointmentItem inspector with a custom form.

Basically, you need to write code that gets triggered on the [NewInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147644.aspx) event and display your form instead and cancel the standard inspector.